# Find, renaming, and replacing files

Tags: python

I need to update an existing directory with files that are provided in a Patch directory.
This is what I'm starting with.  All commented out by me and then I try to build each line.

```
# $SourceDirectory = Patch folder that has files in any number of sub folders
# $DestDirectory = Application folder that has the files that need patching 
# $UnMatchedFilesFolder = A Folder where SourceFiles go that don't have a match in $DestDirectory
# import os.path
# import os.listdir
#
# Create list1 of files from $SourceDirectory
# For each file (excluding directory names) in List1 (including subfolders), search for it in $DestDirectory and its subfolders;
# If you find the file by the same name, then create a backup of that file with .old;
#   move $DestDirectoryPathAndFile to $DestDirectoryPathAndFile.old;
#   print "Creating backup of file";
#   After the backup is made, then copy the file from the $SourceDirectory to the;
#   exact same location where it was found in the $DestDirectory.  ;
# Else;
#   move file to UnmatchedFilesDirectory.;
#  If the number of files in $UnMatchedFilesDirectory =/ 0;
#   Create list3 from $UnmatchedFilesDirectory
#  print "The following files in $UnMatchedFilesDirectory will need to be installed individually";
# Print "Automated Patching completed.";

# Print "Script completed";
```

Comment: This looks like Pseudo code and not Python? Might want to edit it so its clear what is meant to comments and whats not. If you can't tell the difference on pseudo code and real code after 2 weeks, that class is a waste of your time.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us examples of the code you have written and where it is breaking and what you are expecting? We could all just write the code for you, but if you are attempting to learn python that wouldn't be too helpful.

Comment: Yes, this is psuedo code that I have just written by hand getting some rough ideas down.  It in no way, shape or form is real code.  I've slept a little, and now I'm going to give it another shot.  Stay tuned.

Comment: I switched this up a little bit and used windows powershell to do this. There was a lot of scope creep that started to lead into SQL server stuff, and outlook, so powershell was the easy option.  Pretty simple to learn, although I think python will be better.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the previous post, I am skeptical of the course you are following based on the information given. Based on the document given, there are far better sites/tutorials available for free to help you learn Python/programming. That said, Stack Overflow is a friendly place, and so I hope to provide you with information which will help you on your way:

```
import os
source_dir =r"D:\temp"
dest_dir=r"D:\temp2"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    # os.walk 'root' steps through subdirectories as we iterate
    # this allows us to join 'root' and 'file' without missing any sub-directories
    for file in files:
        exist_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        # expected_file represents the fullpath of a file we are looking to create/replace
        expected_file = exist_path.replace(source_dir, dest_dir)
        current = os.path.join(root, file)
        if os.path.exists(expected_file):
            print "The file %s exists, os.rename with '.old' before copying %s" % (current, exist_path)
            # .. note:: we should rename to .bkp here, then we would correctly copy the file below without conflict
        print "Now %s doesn't exist, we are free to copy %s" % (expected_file, exist_path)
```